# Trying to get input value through ajax with Django

Tags: jquery, python, ajax, django

I'm trying to get the input value through with django using ajax is not working I hope you can help me I have seen the code all the day and I do not find the error.

It suppose to give the value by an alert window.

**views.py**

```
def form(request):
    return render_to_response('prueba2.html')

from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
@csrf_exempt
def form_ajax(request):
    if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
        nombre = request.POST['nombre']
        return HttpResponse(nombre)
```

**file.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(function() {

$(document).on('submit', '#fomulario', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    $.ajax({
        type:'POST',
        url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/form_ajax/',
        async: 'true',
        data: $('#nombre').val(),       

        success: function(data) {
                alert(data)
            },  

    });

})  


});
</script>

</body>

<form id="fomulario"> 
<label for="Nombre">Nombre</label>
<input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="hola">
<input type="submit">
</form>

<div id="valor"></div>

</html>
```

All suppose to work properly if I make something like this:

**views.py**

```
   def form(request):
        return render_to_response('prueba2.html')

    from django.views.decorators.csrf import csrf_exempt
    @csrf_exempt
    def form_ajax(request):
        if request.is_ajax() and request.method == 'POST':
            #nombre = request.POST['nombre']
            return HttpResponse('HELLO THIS IS ME...')
```

I think django is not taking the value of the input name.

Do you have any idea how to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should set param name.

```
 $.ajax({
    type:'POST',
    url:'http://127.0.0.1:8000/form_ajax/',
    async: 'true',
    data: {nombre: $('#nombre').val()},       

    success: function(data) {
        alert(data)
    },  

});
```